# What is the different between one company's two OTCMKTS symbols?

Tags: stocks

[image]

I noticed that there are two OTCMKTS for Tencent. One is `TCEHY` and the other is `TCTZF` - what it the difference?

Any helpufl information to understand more about OTCMKTS stocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not looked in details but apparently the company has (at least) a dual listing in Hong Kong (its main listing, ticker 700) and in the US (ticker TCTZF). It also has an ADR (TCEHY), the underlying of which is the HK line.

The two US listings essentially trade at the same price and will provide very similar returns but a major difference is that TCTZF pays dividends in HKD whereas TCEHY pays its dividends in USD. The latter may be more convenient depending on the account you use to trade the stock.

The ADR line is also more liquid.

Comment: when I tried to trade via my broker, something weird happened. the broker told me to order via a phone call but it's night time in the US. While the market is closed when the day time in US and in HK market there is not "pre-market" or "after-hours" trading... I'm just wondering how people trade HK stocks in US OTCMKTS.